# Приложение крашится при первом запуске, при втором запускается нормально

Tags: java, android, retrofit, асинхронность, rxjava

Всем привет!
Собственно, есть такая проблема.
Я работаю над своим маленьким open-source приложением, которое получает данные о погоде из https://openweathermap.org и показывает их на экране.
Исходный код есть на [гитхабе](https://github.com/LilHelix/simple-weather-app).

Так вот, собственно, в чём проблема:
Есть асинхронный запрос к API openweathermap.org,

```
call.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(weatherData -> {
                List<Prognosis> prognosisList = weatherData.getPrognosisList();
                mItems = ConvertUtils.convert(prognosisList);

                realm.beginTransaction();
                final WeatherData weatherDataToCopy = realm.copyToRealm(weatherData);
                realm.insertOrUpdate(weatherDataToCopy);
                realm.commitTransaction();
                realm.close();
```

...и есть код, который заполняет поле `mItems` - список проксирующих сущностей `Item` между базой данных и `RecyclerView`, создающий `ListAdapter` и устанавливающий этот адаптер для `RecyclerView`

```
 
    if (weatherDatas == null || weatherDatas.size() == 0) {
            actWithDataFromApi(realm);
        } else {
            actWithDataFromDB(weatherDatas);
            realm.close();
        }
```

```
    ListAdapter mAdapter = new ListAdapter(mItems, this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

...и при первом запуске оно крашится **всегда** с `NullPointerException`, исходящем из метода `getItemCount()` из адаптера для `RecyclerView`, но при втором запуске приложение не крашится и сразу же на экране отображается вся информация о погоде.

В чём может быть проблема и как её пофиксить?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Добавил необходимое.

Comment: Пркажите стектрейс. И что это за последний участок кода?  Этот код из разных мест программы или из одно? И ещё код адаптера покажите.

Comment: [стектрейс](http://pastebin.com/QV76X75Z) и [адаптер](https://github.com/LilHelix/simple-weather-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bprotsyk/example1/adapters/ListAdapter.java)

Второе -- участок когда из метода onCreate(), первое -- участок из метода, отвечающего за асинхронный запрос

Answer (score 0):

Всё, я нашёл способ пофиксить проблему.
Если кому-то интересно, в RxJava при создании `Observable<T>` и вызове метода `subscribe(item -> {})` данными, оказывается, нужно оперировать внутри лямбды.
Конкретнее -- я просто создал внутри лямбды `ListAdapter` и обновил `RecyclerView`.

Надеюсь, это кому-нибудь да пригодится.

Comment: RxJava лишь выносит Ваш запрос в отдельный поток и не спасает (из коробки) от проблем со сменой конфигурации (к примеру, смене ориентации экрана). Т.е. если в момент того, как идет запрос в сеть (в бэкграунде), устройство перевернуть, то в вашей лямбде, которая будет работать в мэйн потоке Вы получите NPE, т.к. система уже не найдет старый  RecyclerView. Нужно использовать обычный колбэк или EventBus, который можно построить на той же Rx

Comment: я сейчас проверил подобную ситуацию, и да, действительно, такая проблема есть.
спасибо за информацию!